# Unexpected line break when importing to SQL from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I when I import a pipe delimited .txt file I receive from a client every once in a while, one of my records will import into the raw table with a line break in the tuple. But when I look at the .txt file I see neither `{CR}{LF}` or `{LF}`.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Has anyone else ever experienced this?

Comment: Is the issue reproducible if you try re-importing the same file?   If so, can you reduce the file to the smallest possible file that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is there an extra "|" in the data somewhere? I've seen similar results when SSIS sees an extra delimiter and the columns get out of sync. Check the line that's causing the problem in the file, *and the line before it* carefully. With my data, it was pipe-delimited customer data with part of the address something like "12 Chape| Road".

Comment: @TabAlleman yes I can, when I look at Notepad++ I don't see any weird characters or extra pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues. I ended up stripping out any \n or \r escape characters from string data after it had already come into the data flow using either a derived column or a custom script component. That fixed the problem for me. It helps to enable the data viewer to see what the data looks like as you are debugging.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done going forward but I really want to know why it's happening!

Comment: Could you please share the details of how you resolved this issue using SSIS derived column

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this before and found that in some cases SSIS could only recognize tabs, linefeeds, & carriage returns using the hexadecimal format:

```
x0009 - tab
x000A - feed
x000D - return
```

Try using something like this in your derived column:

```
(DT_STR,50,1252)TRIM(LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( *{your_column}*,"\x0009",""),"\x000A",""),"\x000D","")))
```